# Amazon instant videos stopped working in chrome (I did install HAL) and it works in firefox

Tags: google-chrome

since last week I can watch Amazon Instant videos only works in firefox but not in chrome, I re-installed hal but still doesn't help . the progress bar goes but it shows black screen video with no sound.

my chrome version is Version 20.0.1132.57
my ubuntu 12.10 is 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's Chrome's bug. You could go to Chrome official community forum and ask people how to make it work around it or just wait for next version hoping that this bug will be fixed.

Good luck.